# Xerox WorkCentre 6015B - Requires authentication / Credentials required in order to print

Tags: printing, 19.10, xerox

I have 2 computers, a desktop computer and a laptop. Both have a dual boot, with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10.

My printer is a Xerox WorkCentre 6015B.

Everything worked well with Ubuntu 19.04 and before also (I use Ubuntu since 12.04). I configure exactly the same way on both computers and now I get the same error message on both computers saying:

```
Requires authentication / Credentials required in order to print.
```

The printer works with Windows 10, so I think there is not a problem with the printer. I created a live USB with Ubuntu 19.04, and I can configure the printer and I can print. So this comes from Ubuntu 19.10 I believe.

The error message says "requires authentication", but I don't know which username or password I need and where to put them. Before Ubuntu never asked me to authenticate. Do you think it could be a bug? Have any of you encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

I’ve had this same issue with Pop!_OS (an Ubuntu-based distro) after upgrading to 19.10. At my workplace we print via a print queue with two printers. When I configured the printer in Pop!_OS 18.04 I remember that I needed to enter a username/password set up by the IT team only once. After updating to 19.10 I see this notification appear but that takes me to the print queue where I could do nothing, which seems to be the same problem.

To solve it I stopped CUPS:
`sudo service cups stop`

And then edited the file `/etc/cups/printers.conf` (you’ll need root access). Look for your printer (usually the `<DefaultPrinter ...>` block) and look for the line that starts with `AuthInfoRequired`. In my case it was `AuthInfoRequired none` and I changed it to `AuthInfoRequired username,password`.

After that I restarted CUPS:
`sudo service cups start`

And after sending a job to the printer, I had this [printer authentication dialogue window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBUYO.png) show up. I entered the username/password, clicked on “Remember password” and this fixed it for me.

I hope that helps.

Also, it might be worth comparing to the previous configuration files, I think they are kept in `/etc/cups` with a `.0` extension. Unfortunately I had already messed with them and I lost the original ones. I suspect that the issue must be there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. As I do not have Ubuntu 19.10 installed on my computer, I use a Live-USB.
I followed all the steps and indeed, I get a printer authentication dialogue window. The username is already written (ubuntu) and it asks for a password. I leave it empty and press enter, but it does not print. Which password should I use ? I could install Ubuntu 19.10 again on my computer, but if I do it but that it doesn't work, it would be time wasted.

Anyway thank very much for your answer again. Hope you can answer my new questions.

CD

Comment: Unfortunately that’s a printer-specific setting. I’d double-check that you don’t have any authentication set up, in which case `AuthInfoRequired none` would be enough. Also, I’d try to set a username/password on the printer and use that in the authentication dialogue window.

I’m afraid I can’t provide any further advice since  the printer in my workplace is fully managed by the IT department.