# How to fix failing connection to SAMBA print share (Ubuntu 19.10)?

Tags: networking, printing, samba

I have lately installed Ubuntu 19.10 and wanted to connect to the printing services on a local network, shared for linux users via SAMBA. While this worked flawlessly with 18.04/18.10, it's stopped to work for me. On `journalctl -r`, I get the following error (parameters obfuscated) when pressing the *Verify* button in the *Printer Properties* dialogue:

```
gnome-control-center.desktop: Kinit for user@DOMAIN to access SERVER failed: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm
gnome-control-center.desktop: Caught non-fatal exception.  Traceback:
gnome-control-center.desktop: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py", line 2861, in on_btnSMBVerify_clicked
gnome-control-center.desktop:     os.O_RDWR, 0o777)
gnome-control-center.desktop: smbc.PermissionError: (13, 'Permission denied')
gnome-control-center.desktop: Continuing anyway..
```

Also, I repeatedly get a notification requesting SAMBA credentials when printing the test page (the queue lists the job as "held for authentication"). The latter might be because my credentials don't seem to be saved in the Printer Properties as long as their verification fails.

Although [that problem](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2157374-ubuntu-version-18-smb-printer) seems to be somewhat older, I tried [this recent recommendation](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1705753.html) from the Debian bug mailing list, suggesting to switch off Kerberos by altering the corresponding Python script. Please, read the details how to do this there. However, after doing this I get another error:

```
gnome-control-center.desktop: Caught non-fatal exception.  Traceback:
gnome-control-center.desktop: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py", line 2861, in on_btnSMBVerify_clicked
gnome-control-center.desktop:     os.O_RDWR, 0o777)
gnome-control-center.desktop: smbc.NoEntryError: (2, 'No such file or directory')
gnome-control-center.desktop: Continuing anyway..
```

Hope to get some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the meantime, people have found a workaround for the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1849859) described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186501/835198):

1. `sudo service cups stop`
2. In the file `/etc/cups/printers.conf`, sudo-change the line `AuthInfoRequired none` to `AuthInfoRequired username,password` in the block for your printer, in my case the `<DefaultPrinter ...>`
3. `sudo service cups start`
4. Printing should then ask you for the credentials, in my case following the pattern `DOMAIN\username` and as usual the password, along with a "Remember" checkbox.

**Note 1:** To see the [checkbox](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186501/835198), I had to use the "Print ..." option of a recent Gnome application (like Eye of Gnome, `eog`). It didn't show up in the password dialogue of the job queue.

**Note 2:** I wasn't asked for a password in the *old job queue dialogue* reachable via the "Additional Printer Settings ...". However, in the *new job queue* of the printer directly listed in *Gnome Settings->Devices->Printers*, one can click on "Jobs" and should see a request for authentication above the queued items.

Currently, it seems that there are two GUI generations mixed in an unfortunate fashion.

Generally, however, `printers.conf` [should not be changed manually](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man5/printers.conf.5.html) which is why waiting for the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1849859) to be fixed seems sensible, too.

Comment: I think the part about having to include the workgroup in the username field with a backslash should be in bold letters. It took me hours to fight this details before I found this answer! I had added printer with URL like `smb://MYWORKGROUP/server.tld/myqueue` and CUPS seems to ignore the workgroup in the URL because you still have to enter the workgroup in the user name field for the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have hit bug [#1849859](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1849859)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that issue. Yes, it seems to be an unfixed bug. Maybe you can turn your answer into a real one, once the fix is deployed. Thx.

Comment: looking forward to hear about the progress on that bug, thanks @andreas for the work!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just hit a similar bug when setting up a printer in Ubuntu 22.04.

```
úno 05 10:56:47 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: Continuing anyway..
úno 05 10:56:47 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: smbc.NoEntryError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
úno 05 10:56:47 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]:     f = ctx.open ("smb://%s/%s" % (host, share),
úno 05 10:56:47 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py", line 2879, in on_btnSMBVerify_clicked
úno 05 10:56:47 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]:     raise exc
úno 05 10:56:47 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/pysmb.py", line 180, in failed
úno 05 10:56:47 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]:     smbc_auth.failed (e)
úno 05 10:56:47 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py", line 2883, in on_btnSMBVerify_clicked
úno 05 10:56:47 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: Caught non-fatal exception.  Traceback:
úno 05 10:56:10 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: Continuing anyway..
úno 05 10:56:10 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: smbc.NoEntryError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
úno 05 10:56:10 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]:     f = ctx.open ("smb://%s/%s" % (host, share),
úno 05 10:56:10 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py", line 2879, in on_btnSMBVerify_clicked
úno 05 10:56:10 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]:     raise exc
úno 05 10:56:10 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/pysmb.py", line 180, in failed
úno 05 10:56:10 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]:     smbc_auth.failed (e)
úno 05 10:56:10 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/newprinter.py", line 2883, in on_btnSMBVerify_clicked
úno 05 10:56:10 luks-14ITL5 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop[446101]: Caught non-fatal exception.  Traceback:
```

I had to install `sudo apt-get install python3-smbc smbclient`.
When setting up the printer I always clicked on "Verify" though this always resulted in this error. However, when I saved the credential information and didn't verify the connection, the printer started running.
So you might try to just skip the verify step and just directly save the printer.